# How far back and what browsers should I test?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

I have written a website and I found out a part of it doesn't work with IE8 but works with IE9.

That made me think about testing it with different versions.

My question is two fold:

1. What browsers should I test primarily? Should I require specific browsers to work with our app?
2. How far back in each browser should I 'allow' and test?

I see that I can test what browser they have so now it's just a matter of what I should program again?

What is everyone's experience with this?

**UPDATE**

The purpose of the site is to give our clients a portal to their customers account information. They will go to our clients website and then will be directed to our portal to register/login and view their account.

Does that help?

Comment: This depends on the purpose of your website, your target audience, and your personal preferences.

Comment: I have no experience in this so my personal preference wouldn't be a good answer. I'll update the post as to the target audience and purpose.

Comment: Depends on what you want. You typically don't care about the versions, but then there's IE

Comment: Yeah IE is where I found my problem. I wish I should just block all IE users and tell them to get a better browser. lol

Comment: I currently go back to IE 7. But I typically don't worry too much about Chrome and Firefox.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: @webNoob wow seriously? Is it because they usually work okay or you just don't bother with them??

Comment: Close it if you want but my question stands, how far back do I test for? I'm new at this so I'm not sure why it should be closed.

Comment: @ErocM It's because such questions are too subjective to be answered, there is no single right answer (it will vary too much between people), and it will change over time (making it too localized).  It's also a topic likely to result in debates and extended discussion, as mentioned in the close reason.

Comment: it's bs that this was closed. It was a legitimate question. How the hell do I know how far back in each browser to test with? I was asking an opinion of the community.

Comment: @ErocM Exactly, you were asking an opinion of the community, and such questions are *specifically* listed as not being welcome here.

Comment: @ErocM Haha, yeah I said that one wrong. I put a ton of effort making it work in I.E. then I open my Chrome and Firefox browsers only to see them displayed exactly how I wanted them to. It's a good feeling.

Comment: It's debatable whether a question like this should be closed IMO, especially after the update.  It's maybe still off topic, since it's more a question of project management, than a specific programming question.

Comment: @dbaseman How is it debatable?  The OP is specifically saying that he's polling for opinions.  It's textbook "not constructive", and "too localized" as well, as no answer will be able to stand for an extended period of time.

Comment: @Servy I agree that it definitely should be re-worded.  Assuming the Op rewords from *What is everyone's experience with this?* to *What is the correct way to approach this*, then I'd say it's borderline, although maybe more on topic for Programmers or Project Managers, than for SO.

Comment: I'd consider reading the following article regarding progressive enhancement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement with a good solid semantic markup and possibly HTML 5 Shim for IE6 & a fluid layout like Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Layouts there's no reason why your sites shouldn't be accessible to as wide a range of viewports and users as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They'll probably close this question, but I'll answer it anyway.

You can start by checking [browser market share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) which will give you a rough idea of what browsers are out there in the wild.

You'd then need to take this information, along with an idea of who your target audience is, and make sure that you've got a successful website for the userbase you want.  Generally speaking, IE8 is still widespread out there in the wild, and will continue to be for some time, as that is the last version of IE that works with Windows XP.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that you know should be closed.  Vote to close and then don't answer.  Questions such as these, those that are *not constructive* are questions that *can* be answered but *shouldn't* be.  You should know better given how long you've been active on the site.

Comment: Although his question did help me with what browser to test with... thank you Dave.

Comment: Not everyone agrees on which questions should be closed, and last I checked, this was a community run site.  @DaveMarkle didn't say he necessarily agreed the question should be closed, just that it probably would be.

Comment: @dbaseman When the SE community has determined that a type of question is not appropriate and should be closed (this one is not borderline at all; it's very clear that it should be closed) then you shouldn't ignore that and answer it anyway.  If you feel that the guidelines for whether or not such a question should be closed the appropriate mechanism is to go to meta and discuss the issue.  That is the way in which the community participates in such matters.

Comment: Please don't comment on answers to questions which are closed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to collect stats on your website and see what users use to access it. Depending on the nature of the site this distribution can be quiet different.

For instance if the site is for the corporate users you should expect a lot of IE, but safari would be the least of your concerns.

Answering this question without the stat would be just guessing.

Comment: But when you first launch the site, you have to guess.

Comment: which is our case... we haven't launched just yet.

Comment: @ErocM No, it's not BS, you simply don't understand the guidelines of what is and is not considered an appropriate question to ask on SO.  Had you spent some more time reading the FAQ you would have known that before asking the question.  Since you didn't, the result is a closed question.

Comment: I've been on this site long enough to know how to ask a question. I was asking an opinion of what people do in THEIR EXPERIENCE since I have none.

Comment: @ErocM Apparently you *haven't* been on this site long enough then, because the guidelines are very specific that what you're asking is not appropriate.